# Github Blog Post Action

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm new to the world of programming and currently getting my Github profile readme together.
I'm currently stuck on, trying to get my blog post action to run and can't seem to get it running.

Here is the code I came across and used as well as screenshots regarding the issues.

[First image of action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wq0d5.png)
[Second image of action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwHew.png)

I tried going to the discussions section of the the git repo but haven't found anything in relation to this issue.

````yaml
name: Latest Hashnode Blog Post
on:
  schedule:
    # Runs Every 7 days
    - cron: '0 * * * *'
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  update-readme-with-blog:
    name: Update this repo's README with the latest Hashnode blog posts
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: gautamkrishnar/blog-post-workflow@master
        with:
          comment_tag_name: "HASHNODE"
          commit_message: "Update readme with the latest Hashnode Blog data"
          feed_list: "https://roninking.hashnode.dev/rss.xml"```
````

Comment: I found the answer from a guy on discord that had the same issue. He had to change the action permissions to read and write.

Comment: What is the solution? Please post a link.

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this question, you need to go into your repo, then click on settings, the click on actions on the left side, the general and finally scroll down towards the bottom and you'll see Workflow Permissions and then click on read and write permissions then hit save.

```
[Image 1 - finding settings in repo][1] 
[Image 2 - finding actions and general tab left side][2]
[Image 3 - finding workflow permissions and clicking on read, write][3]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjxft.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzL86.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxLtC.png
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).